# downloaded file content not showing

Tags: c#

i am using bellow code to download the files.but it downloads the file but not showing the contents or it not opens the file. the file paths are different. my project is on different path and i am taking the files from different path. Those files are not stored on project path.file paths,size,name are stored in database.

```
Crc32 crc = new Crc32();
ZipOutputStream s = new ZipOutputStream(File.Create(
       @"C:\Documents and Settings\admin\My Documents\Downloads\Evidence.zip"));

s.SetLevel(0); // 0 - store only to 9 - means best compression

FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(@"c:\boot.ini");
byte[] buffer = new byte[fs.Length];

fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
  {
    string fileNamePath = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["EvidencePath"]);
    string fileNmae = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["EvidenceName"]);

    ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(ZipEntry.CleanName(@fileNmae));
    entry.DateTime = DateTime.Now;
    entry.Comment = "test file";
    entry.ZipFileIndex = i + 1;
    entry.Size = fs.Length;

    //fs.Close();

    crc.Reset();
    crc.Update(buffer);
    entry.Crc = crc.Value;

    s.PutNextEntry(entry);
    s.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    //Response.WriteFile(""+fileNamePath);
  }
  s.Finish();
  s.Close();
  fs.Close();
}

ShowMessageBox("Downloaded....");
```

Comment: Could you please verify if code is actually related to the question? I reformated the code to find piece that writes results somewhere... but I still don't see anything beyond creation of a zip file... And strange ShowMessageBox call which does not make a lot of sence in question marked ASP.Net...

Comment: ShowMessageBox is function in my code

Answer (score 0):

I only took a quick peek at your code, but if I understand you correctly, nothing is being written to the file, is that correct? You might try adding the following near the end:

```
S.Flush()
```

This should probably happen automatically when you close the stream, but I've seen cases where it does not, for whatever reason. Flushing will ensure any data in the buffer is actually written to the file before you close it.